# setdiff() function in R supposed to exclude numbers but it isn't

Tags: r, set-difference

So I am using `setdiff()` function for 2 vectors. As I understand if do

```
a <- c(5,6,7)
b <- (5,7,9,10,11)
```

`setdiff(a,b)` should give 6

I am using one vector

```
 sort(unique(probable_digit_matter_169))
 [1]  1  2  3  4  5  7  8  9 14 15 16 18 19 21 22 23 25 26 27 30 32 34 36 37 38 40 41 42 45 47 49 51 52 56 58 59 61 62 64 65
```

so `setdiff(c(4:68),unique(probable_digit_matter_169))` should give elements that are in `c(4:68)` but not in the `unique(probable_digit_matter_169)`

but the answer of

```
> setdiff(c(4:68),sort(unique(probable_digit_matter_169)))
 [1]  6 10 11 12 13 17 20 21 22 23 24 25 28 29 31 33 35 39 43 44 46 48 49 50 51 52 53 54 55 57 60 63 66 67 68
```

as you can see several numbers are here which isn't supposed to be. 21, 22, 23, 25, 49, 51, 52 these numbers are in the vector so when I apply `setdiff()` they should be eliminated. What am I doing wrong ? I couldn't find answers elsewhere. Thank you for not being rude and helping me.

Comment: We don't know what is in that `probable_digit_matter_169` vector unless you show us how to create it.  Just run `dput(probable_digit_matter_169)` and edit the result into your question.

Comment: If I create a vector of the digits and call it "probable_digit_matter_169", then the `setDiff()` statement works as expected, i.e. no 21 nor other common digits.  Is it possible that the duplicated digits in "probable_digit_matter_169" are not integers?

Comment: @TechCommodities no they are digits

Comment: @user2554330 probable_digit_matter_169 is a vector with digits. It's given. I am going to try the dput() and comment back. Thank you

Comment: There are many ways to store digits, and we can't tell which one you used from what you have included so far.